# Wear OS source code — is its AndroidManifest.xml file available?

Tags: android, wear-os

I've gotten interested in Android's Wear OS lately. Although I know that parts of Wear OS's source code is not open source, I was wondering its AndroidManifest.xml file for versions 3 and 3.5 are available, and if so, does anyone know where I could find it?

Comment: An `AndroidManifest.xml` file is required metadata/configuration for an Android app and not specific to any Android version (OS for phone/tablet, watch, automotive).

Answer (score 0):

> Wear OS source code — is its AndroidManifest.xml file available?

AndroidManifest.xml is a file required by apps to register with the Android system. Wear OS is a subset of Android, not an app, and as such does not have an AndroidManifest.xml file.